# How to Take Subset of a Tensor based on set of Index , in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

Given
a: tensor([[3., 5.], [1., 2.],[5., 7.],[4., 6.],[3., 5.]])
index: tensor( [0,0],[3,1])

Is there any Way to Get a[index] is [3,6]